# Taylor series of $\log x$ at $x=2$

Tags: calculus

Good night to everyone.

I have a doubt.

Can I obtain the Taylor serie of $g(x) = \log (x)$ centered at $x=2$ starting in the kwon Maclaurin series of $e^x$ or $1/(1-x)?$

Best regards

Comment: Not sure it is the night for everyone... i.e. in Asia ;-)

Comment: Well, the series needs $a_0=\ln 2$, so at least that you have to pull out of somewhere.

Comment: Did you mean “known” where you wrote “keon?”

Comment: If you get the Taylor series for $1/(x-2)$ at $x=0$, then you can integrate to get the Taylor series for $\log(2-x)$ at $x=0$.  Substitute $z=2-x$ to get the Taylor series for $\log z$ at $z=2$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Let $ f(x)=\ln(x)$.

$$g(x)=\ln(x+2)=\ln(2(1+\frac x2))$$
$$=\ln(2)+\ln(1+\frac x2)$$

$$=\ln(2)+\frac x2-\frac{(\frac x2)^2}{2}+\frac{(\frac x2)^3}{3}-...$$

thus

$$f(x)=g(x-2)$$
$$=\ln(2)+\frac{x-2}{2}-...$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

From your post: The Taylor series of $1/(1-x)$ centered at $2$ is known.

Now set $x\to 1-t,$ so that we have $1/t$.  Then integrate on both sides, with the lower bound $1$ and the upper bound $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=\ln(x+2)$ then $(x+2)f'(x)=1$ and develop for $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$

$(x+2)\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^n+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty 2(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n=1$

Identify with the constant series $1$ gives $\begin{cases}2a_1=1\\a_{n+1}=-\frac n{2(n+1)}a_n\end{cases}$

Therefore $$a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n2^n}\quad\text{and}\quad a_0=f(0)=\ln(2)$$